# Setting background color for all Views using Expo-Route in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I am relatively new to React Native and have been exploring the expo-route. I am struggling to determine how to globally set the background color of all views using expo-router.

I've referred to React Navigation’s documentation, but it seems to be more relevant to React Navigation, not Expo-Route, leading me to question whether I'm missing some fundamental understanding. Link: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/

I've customized the header background and applied other stylings, my objective is seemingly straightforward: I wish to **change the background color to blue for all views collectively**.

Could someone please clarify whether there is a way within expo-route to apply a universal background color, or perhaps enlighten me on any misconceptions I might have about expo-route and React Navigation?

An image to show the code and the folder structure:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the color of the background directly by setting the option `contentStyle: { backgroundColor: "your_color" }` in your Stack component.

Here's an example:

```
            <Stack
                screenOptions={{
                    contentStyle: { backgroundColor: "your_color" },
                }}
            />
```

You can find more details about the props in the
[React Navigation documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator/#contentstyle).

Hope I helped